# How to check data available or not in the results?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ") FROM `batch_list` WHERE `batch_venue_id` = '1' GROUP BY `batch_venue_id`.
```

This is the result array I am getting it.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ")] => 1,2,3,4,7 ) ).
```

Now What I am doing is. I am passing the 1,7 to check this is available or not in the result if found then display the message.

```
$days='1,7';
        $result12 =$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ",")')
                    ->from('batch_list')
                    ->where('batch_venue_id',$venue_id)
                    //->where('days',$days)
                    ->group_by('batch_venue_id')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
```

So I am getting the result [GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ")] => 1,2,3,4,7 ) now I have to check the $days available or not in the result.
 Would you help me out how to check this?

Comment: i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Don't use GROUP_CONCAT here. And define `$days` as array `$days = [1, 7]`. Then you can use `array_intersect` for your check.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, can you help me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `explode()` and `array_intersect()`,

```
<?php
$day_str = '1,7';
$result_str = '1,2,3,4,7';
$result = explode(',',$result_str);
$days = explode(',',$day_str);

if(count(array_intersect($result, $days)) > 0){
    echo "$day_str are in $result_str";
}else{
    echo "$day_str are not in $result_str"; 
}
?>
```

**Suggestion:** You can use an alias when selecting columns from table

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ") as result FROM `batch_list` WHERE `batch_venue_id` = '1' GROUP BY `batch_venue_id`
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/MG5kt

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: @user9437856 okk , you can see the DEMO

Comment: What I did, I change some value in your demo, from 1,7 to 1,5 and it gives me the output      1,5 are not in 1,2,3,4,7............ I think 1 is available but 5 is not available.

Comment: do you want both days available or it will work if any single day is inside the result?

Comment: Any single day is available then display the message. if I try 1,4 then available but if I try 1,5 then one is available but 5 not

Comment: @user9437856 see my EDIT again, just replace the line `== count($days)` to `> 0` and let me know is it working with different days value or not?

Comment: I am getting the results in  [GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ")] => 1,2,3,4,7  so how do I display? I mean I have to use like $result_str = "What I have to add here"

Comment: Eg https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html .You need to use $this-db->query for that please see my post below you will get back to know and making an alias for that fields

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, I tried your updated code but it's not working. I mean I try again 1,5 and this time it's showing available.

Comment: @user9437856 I guess I'm  little bit confused what you want? This is what you say on your previous msg **Any single day is available then display the message**

Comment: Yes, Correct but 5 is not available in the list. I again tried 8,1 and it's showing available

Comment: @user9437856 could you plz edit your question and show us what is you expected output when it is 1,7 or 1,5 or 7,7 or any combination

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, What I am doing is, I have a days number in the table and days which coming from the user end. From user end days number will check if that number is available or not in the list. If found anyone then display return true or else false.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you maybe want to do this in pure MySQL code. 
 
If you want you can with this MySQL code.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ")
  , MAX(
      CASE
        # match this with the batch_days IN (1, 7) part in the CROSS JOIN list length
        WHEN values_exist_check.batch_list_count = 2 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS values_exists
FROM batch_list
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS batch_list_count
  FROM
    batch_list
  WHERE
      batch_venue_id = 1
    AND
      batch_days IN (1, 7)
) AS values_exist_check
WHERE
 batch_venue_id = 1
GROUP BY
 batch_venue_id
```

**Result**

```
| GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ") | values_exists |
| --------------------------------------- | ------------- |
| 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7                     | 1             |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zWDzZV1ngoXth1azL7NCm/0)

For the missing 1 and 7 values this is the result

**Result**

```
| GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ") | values_exists |
| --------------------------------------- | ------------- |
| 2, 3, 4, 5, 6                           | 0             |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zWDzZV1ngoXth1azL7NCm/2)

**Edited**

After a review i was realizing that mine last query was to much off a workaround to be confirm with the ANSI SQL GROUP BY standard. 
The query below

```
SELECT 
 table.column
 , (SELECT 1) # literal SQL statement/expression
FROM 
 table
GROUP BY 
 table.colum
```

is confirm with the ANSI SQL GROUP BY standard (MySQL forces this with sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY) because `(SELECT 1)` is a literal SQL statement/expression and not depending from the GROUP BY resultset 
Meaning the query can be optimized without using a `CROSS JOIN`

**Query**

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ")
  , (
      CASE 
        WHEN (
           SELECT
              COUNT(*) AS batch_list_count
           FROM
             batch_list
           WHERE
             batch_venue_id = 1
           AND
             batch_days IN (1, 7)
        # match this with the batch_days IN (1, 7) above        
        ) = 2                              
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0       
      END
    )
FROM batch_list
WHERE
 batch_venue_id = 1
GROUP BY
 batch_venue_id
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zWDzZV1ngoXth1azL7NCm/4)

Edited because off comment:

> Thanks for the answer, I am trying like 1,2,3,4,7 checking with 1,5 if
>   anyone is available then it' should display the message.

From the question i got the impression the the string `1,5` fully needed to be found within `1,2,3,4,7`/ But cleary this is not not what you want/need.

This query will give the correct results.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ")
  , (
      CASE 
        WHEN (
           SELECT
              COUNT(*) AS batch_list_count
           FROM
             batch_list
           WHERE
             batch_venue_id = 1
           AND
             batch_days IN (1, 7)      
        ) >= 1                              
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0       
      END
    ) AS value_exists
FROM batch_list
WHERE
 batch_venue_id = 1
GROUP BY
 batch_venue_id
```

**Result**

```
| GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ") | value_exists |
| --------------------------------------- | ------------ |
| 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7                        | 1            |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zWDzZV1ngoXth1azL7NCm/4)

PHP should display the message, it's didn't program in the codeigniter framework for some time now. So mine code could be wrong.

But i believe your code needs to be something like

```
$result12 =$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ",") AS list')
                     # not sure if a second select() chain like this was allowed or not, i can't remember annymore.
                    ->select('
                        (
                           CASE 
                              WHEN (
                                  SELECT
                                    COUNT(*) AS batch_list_count
                                  FROM
                                    batch_list
                                  WHERE
                                    batch_venue_id = 1
                                  AND
                                    batch_days IN (1, 5)      
                                  ) >= 1                              
                              THEN 1
                              ELSE 0       
                            END 
                      ) AS value_exists
                   ')
                    ->from('batch_list')
                    ->where('batch_venue_id',$venue_id)
                    //->where('days',$days)
                    ->group_by('batch_venue_id')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();

if( is_array($result12) ) {
  if (isset($result12[0]) && isset($result12[0]->value_exists) && (((int)$result12[0]->value_exists) == 1)
     echo "<message>"; // display available message
  else 
     echo "<message>"; // display non available message
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I am trying like 1,2,3,4,7 checking with 1,5 if anyone is available then it' should display the message.

Comment: "if anyone is available then it' should display the message" right @user9437856 if only off them is available your question said something else...

Comment: give me some time to check

Comment: I thought, I can store all the value in the variable and can compare it if found match then it will display the message or else create it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `->result_array();` instead of `->result();` because it would treated as normal array not array of objects.

Than you can use `in_array()`,array_search methods etc to find if the elements are in the array or not

Or you can use `find_in_set` method to check values are there or not.

If you are using result method then you need to fetch it as object as of sql query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(batch_days SEPARATOR ", ") as test FROM `batch_list` WHERE `batch_venue_id` = '1' GROUP BY `batch_venue_id`.
```

Using PHP 
the variable string you can fetch as `$result12[0]->test;`

or using foreach loop

$ar_match=[1,7]

```
  foreach($result12 as $val)
    {
    $ar[]=$val;
    }
```

now $ar is single dimensional array You can use **array_intersect()**. Checking to see if one array's elements are in another array in PHP